# PHP code allows logging in without correct password

Tags: php, mysql, admin

I'm writing a PHP code for my website. Currently, there's some problems with my code.

Here's my code. Ignore some Malay language used, I'd tried to translate most of them.

```
<?php
session_start();
include "../library/inc.connectiondb.php";

$txtUser  = $_POST['txtUser'];
$txtPass  = $_POST['txtPass'];

if(trim($txtUser) == "") {
  echo "<b>User ID</b> is empty, please fill";
  include "login.php";
}
else if(strlen(trim($txtPass)) <= 5) {
  echo "<b>Password</b> is less then 6 characters, please fix";
  include "login.php";
}
else {  
  $sqlPeriksa = "SELECT userID FROM admin WHERE userID='$txtUser'";
  $qryPeriksa = mysql_query($sqlPeriksa, $sambung);
  $hslPeriksa = mysql_num_rows($qryPeriksa);

  if($hslPeriksa == 0) {
    # If username doesn't exist
    echo "<b>UserID</b> doesn't exist";
    include "login.php";
  }

  else {
    $sqlPassword = "SELECT passID FROM admin WHERE (userID='$txtUser' && passID='$txtPass')";
    $qryPassword = mysql_query($sqlPeriksa, $sambung);
    $hslPassword = mysql_num_rows($qryPassword);

    if($hslPassword < 1) {
      # If password is incorrect
      echo "<b>Password</b> is incorrect";
      include "login.php";
    }

    else {
      # If login successful
      $SES_Admin = $txtUser;
      session_register('SES_Admin');

      echo "LOGIN SUCCESSFUL";

      # Redirect to index.php
      echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=index.php'>";
      exit;
    }
  }
}
?>
```

The problem is this code allows me to login even if the password is wrong. I'd done some searches and it still doesn't solve my problem. I'm pretty sure that the problem is at line 27 onwards.

So, if anyone has a solution, please tell me quickly. I'm writing this code for my school, and it had to be finished before next year.

**Edit**
Ok, I'd already placed the **mysql_real_escape_string** in the code just like what many people told me. I don't know how this will help, but the mysql table for this was named "admin". It had 2 fields; userID and passID. To test the code, I'd inserted the value "admin" and "12345678" into the table.

Comment: Passwords not being hashed? Check. User input not being escaped? Check. Security wise this can't get much worse.

Comment: Please don't deploy this code on any publicly visible websites. Spend some time on the [PHP Security Guide](http://php.net/manual/en/security.php) and the [PHP PDO Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) guides before opening this page up for public consumption.

Comment: Also check out this site http://www.securityfocus.com/blogs/262. Google is your friend, and if possible use a publicly available login library.

Answer (score 1):

This is where your problem is:

```
$sqlPassword = "SELECT passID FROM admin WHERE (userID='$txtUser' && passID='$txtPass')";
$qryPassword = mysql_query($sqlPeriksa, $sambung);
$hslPassword = mysql_num_rows($qryPassword);
```

You see, your `mysql_query` is executing `$sqlPeriksa` which is:

```
$sqlPeriksa = "SELECT userID FROM admin WHERE userID='$txtUser'";
```

Instead, your code should be like this:

```
$sqlPassword = "SELECT passID FROM admin WHERE (userID='$txtUser' && passID='$txtPass')";
$qryPassword = mysql_query($sqlPassword, $sambung);
$hslPassword = mysql_num_rows($qryPassword);
```

Please try this out and let us know what happens.

[edit/additional] : I strongly suggest that you look into the following:

Using PDO:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

Using stored procedures:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

Using PDO + stored procedures:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php (See example #4)

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right! Man, how can I be so careless? Thanks! The code worked flawlessly now (with the mysql_real_escape_string, of course)

Answer (score 0):

just plain troubleshoot is necessary. how many rows are returned? what are the values of userID and passID in the query that returns rows? put some breaks in and see what's going on. i don't see a problem, it but its hard to troubleshoot code posted here since it really can't be run without a db.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason this isn't working as you expected, I suspect the problem might be elsewhere. For example, I don't see you checking if a "SES_Admin" session is already registered. But at the very least you need to replace lines 5 and 6 with this, otherwise someone could potentially delete your entire user table, and do various other malicious things with your MySQL databases.

```
$txtUser  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtUser']);
$txtPass  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtPass']);
```

Please read the article on `mysql_real_escape_string` at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php